# React, how to map comments to display them each in a banner

Tags: reactjs, typescript, maps

I'm new to React and I'm facing a problem that I can't solve. I want to map comments retrieved from the database at the front level. The concern being that in some cases I have several user comments that I want to display each in a banner. I almost got there but currently in the case that I am exploring, I have three comments but these three comments are displayed in succession in three identical banners. While I would like them to appear each in their respective banner. Thank you in advance for your help !

```
`const { actions } = useGetActionsFromReport(sarId, WorkflowActionEnum.ASK_FOR_MODIFICATION)
const comments = actions?.map((action) => action.comment || '')
return (
<ContentWithAccessControl error={suspiciousActivityReportError}>
   <StepLayout>
      <Styled.Container data-testid="sar-initialisation-step-container">
        {comments && comments.map((comment) => {
          return (
            <Banner
              key={comment}
              label={t('redaction.initialisation.comments.label', { comments })}
              testId="get-comments"
              type={Type.INFORMATION} >
              {t('redaction.initialisation.comments.label', { comments })}
            </Banner>)})}`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpdJX.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the index of the element in the array to display the comment in its respective banner:

```
const { actions } = useGetActionsFromReport(sarId, WorkflowActionEnum.ASK_FOR_MODIFICATION);
const comments = actions?.map((action, index) => action.comment || '');

return (
  <ContentWithAccessControl error={suspiciousActivityReportError}>
    <StepLayout>
      <Styled.Container data-testid="sar-initialisation-step-container">
        {comments && comments.map((comment, index) => {
          return (


            <Banner
              key={`comment-${index}`}
              label={t('redaction.initialisation.comments.label', { comment })}
              testId="get-comments"
              type={Type.INFORMATION} 
            >
              {t('redaction.initialisation.comments.label', { comment })}
            </Banner>


          )
        })}
      </Styled.Container>
    </StepLayout>
  </ContentWithAccessControl>
);
```